# Unable to install GWASpoly to R

Tags: r

How can I install R package `GWASpoly`. I have been trying from last week with bundle of different methods. but all went useless. Always showing this msg:

> package ‘GWASpoly’ is not available (for R version 3.3.3)

Can any body help me out in this?

Comment: Did you try to download from here: http://potatobreeding.cals.wisc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/21/2016/08/GWASpoly_download.zip?

Comment: Yes exactly i tried the same way

Comment: Then How do you installed it in R? what command have you used?

Comment: If you have installed required package, try this `install.packages('~/Downloads/GWASpoly_download/GWASpoly_download/GWASpoly_1.3.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type = 'source')`. Replace `'~/Downloads/GWASpoly_download/GWASpoly_download/GWASpoly_1.3.tar.gz'` to the path in your machine.

Comment: Got my problem solved @mt1022

Comment: So what the problem leading to that error?

Comment: thanks for the assistance and kind time

Comment: exactly it was the same error that i was neglecting.

Answer (score 1):

i) Go to this website: http://potatobreeding.cals.wisc.edu/software/

ii) Download the package

iii) In R, install using the following command: `install.packages("~/Downloads/GWASpoly_1.3.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")`